# 1 database read for all views?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tabbed application with multiple views the user can switch 
between:

[image: app]

All of these views are populated by data that I'm reading from my Firebase database. Right now I'm reading the data for each view in the `viewDidLoad()` function of its view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data")
        dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
 ...
```

However, I was wondering it it's possible to just read from the database once and then somehow share the data between all the view controllers of each tab.

The way I'm getting into this storyboard in the first place is with a segue from a different storyboard:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainAppSegue", sender: self)
```

Does anybody know if this is possible? Would I need to save the data in UserDefaults or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. One approach you could take is to move the Firebase read out of the individual view controllers and into a `UITabBarController` subclass. From the subclassed tab bar controller you can access the child view controllers and set the database reference property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data")
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    if let childViewControllers = self.viewControllers {
        for viewController in childViewControllers {
            if let childViewController = viewController as? ChildViewController {
                childViewController.dbRef = dbRef
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'm trying to use your code in a new class I made for my tab bar, and I'm getting the error: `Use of undeclared type 'ChildViewController'`. Is there something else I should put there instead? Also from your code every view controller of the different tabs should have a variable called `dbRef` inside, correct?

Comment: It's an example assuming all of your tab bar controller's child VCs inherit from a UIViewController subclass called ChildViewController and have a dbRef property. Alternatively you could drop the for loop and say `if let childViewController = childViewControllers[0] as? YourViewController { // set dbRef }` and repeat for all 5.